# gapi.auth.signOut(); doesn't sign out

Tags: javascript, google-plus, google-api-js-client

I have been using Google plus authentication in a development app for some time.

I am aware that it is not supposed to work from localhost, but I am experiencing some really erratic behaviour at the moment.

Sign-in is working as expected on any platform, but signOut (gapi.auth.signOut();) behaves differently on different platforms:

1. In Firefox on localhost, signOut works as I expect. I click my signOut button, the callback fires and I am logged out.
2. In Chrome in-cognito on localhost, when I click my signout button, the callback fires, I am logged out and then immediately logged back in again. This is what I have learned to expect in Chrome/localhost.
3. In Chrome (ex-cognito) and any browser on the remote server, the callback function is simply not fired. I have put comments before and after 'gapi.auth.signOut();' and both comments appear in the console, but nothing else happens.

My app is using AngularJS, served from a Node.js/Express server. I am using page-level tags for clientId and scope:

```
<meta name="google-signin-clientid" content="<%= googleClientId %>" />
<meta name="google-signin-scope" content="<%= googleScopes %>" />
```

and data-attributes for other stuff:

```
<span class='g-signin' 
  data-approvalprompt='auto' 
  data-redirecturi='postmessage' 
  data-accesstype='offline' 
  data-cookiepolicy='single_host_origin' 
  data-width='wide' 
  data-callback='signinCallback'>
</span>
```

I am now at a loss to understand what is going wrong.

Any suggestions gratefully received.

Answer (score 0):

This is now working as expected. I didn't fix it, so I guess the Google code must have been broken